# pause a javascript before page refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net, settimeout, onbeforeunload

Im just a newbie in Javascript but I have some serious problem which I searched for many hours on different sources, so I decided to post this question.

How do you stall/pause a javascript before an asp.net page is refreshed or closed?
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

    function confirmExit() {

        var connection = new Ext.data.Connection({
            defaultHeaders: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        connection.request({
            url: 'services/vault/deletewfinstace/'
        });
        refresh();
        //alert("Helloo");
    }

    function refresh() {
        setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload() }, 6000);
    }



</script>
```

In this code I have called a javascript function on the event: window.onbeforeunload, and tried to put a setTimeout() after the function has done its work, but still page refreshes or closes without completing the contents of the function properly. The contents inside the function will execute successfully when I use alert() at the end of the function, but it is somewhat annoying to the user. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that `connection.request` is asynchronous. When you send the request the JS runner will be free, causing the window to reload. Try making the request synchronous if you want the browser to wait before reloading.

Comment: While this is the correct answer to the question, I think it's a good idea to mention it's not very user-friendly to make a browser wait when a user reloads or leaves a page.

Comment: Your observation is correct but synchronous AJAX _can't_ be recommended.

Comment: wow. thank you for that fast answer, i highly appreciated it. I have tried to search for a synchronous request in Ext.js but as i have read they discourage using it. Will it cause some trouble to the page? or server? Thank you again for responding.

Comment: @johnSabre the problem with synchronous requests is that they block the UI thread. The problem with `onBeforeUnload` is that you can't prevent unload, so you need to delay with a blocking call.

Comment: Hi, I have searched about making the call on the page instead (asp page event on unload) or to depend on the session, but I realized it has to be this web service call. @JanDvorak, what do you mean by 'delay with a blocking call'? If only there is an equivalent of alert(), but just for a second or so. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @johnSabre only two things are blocking in Javascript: modal dialogs and SJAX. However, I am not sure about the first.

Answer (score 1):

Create one synchronous Ajax request, this will lock the browser until the response from the server.

Comment: @fmodos John found the other answer worth accepting - I hope you don't mind. You can only hope for an upvote, but 1-ers can't upvote.

Comment: ok, thanks for your update... this is my second day here, so still learning about the rules